# Changing the FROM in PHP email using SMTP

Tags: php, email, smtp

I have the following code that sends an email properly, but the email is received with a FROM value of root@mysite.com .  I would like to have the value of the received email FROM be the value email (that is entered in a contact form) so that the received email can be replied top easily.  Any assistance would be appreciated.
Thanx

```
<?php
if ($_POST["email"]<>'') 
{
 require_once "Mail.php";

 $from = "root@mysite.com";
 $to = "info <info@mysite.com>";
 $subject = "Contact us info from Website";

 $body = "Name: ".$_POST["name"]."\r\n";
 $body .= "Email: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
 $body .= "Phone: ".$_POST["phone"]."\r\n";
 $body .= "Comment: ".nl2br($_POST["comment"]).""; 

 $host = "mail.mysite.com";
 $username = "root@mysite.com";
 $password = "abcdefghijk";

 $headers = array ('From' => $from,'To' => $to, 'Subject' => $subject);
 $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array ('host' => $host, 'auth' => true, 'username' => $username, 'password' => $password));

 $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body, "FROM: $email","-f$replyToEmail");


 mail("$toEmail", $subject, $message, "FROM: $fromEmail","-f$replyToEmail");



 if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
   echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
  } else {
   echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
   }
?>
```

Comment: You're calling both `$smtp->send` _and_ `mail()` - wouldn't that send two emails?

Answer (score 0):

Just set

```
$from = $_POST['email'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You do it like this.

```
 $fromEmail= 'From:'.$_POST["email"];
```

use $fromEmail in your mail function.